# Doctrine DQL - preventing cartesian join

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have following classes in Doctrince (simplified):

```
class Video
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Channel::class, inversedBy="videos", fetch="LAZY")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private ?Channel $channel;
}

class Channel
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Video::class, mappedBy="channel", fetch="LAZY")
     * @OrderBy({"updated" = "DESC"})
     */
    private Collection $videos;

   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class)
    */
   private Collection $users;
}

class User implements UserInterface
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Channel::class)
     */
    private Collection $subscriptions;
}
```

The structure is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPu7Q.png
Basically every user has many subscriptions (channels) and every channel can be subscribed by many users.
Channel has many videos but video has just one channel.

Now I want to write DQL that would load 100 newest videos for a user.
I have this easy DQL:

```
SELECT v FROM App\Entity\Video v 
JOIN App\Entity\Channel ch 
JOIN App\Entity\User u
WHERE u = :user
ORDER BY v.updated DESC
```

There are two problems with this query.

First and biggest one is that it translates into this SQL:

```
SELECT v.* FROM video v INNER JOIN channel ch INNER JOIN user u WHERE i.id = 1 ORDER BY v.updated DESC LIMIT 100;
```

which ignores table user_channel and thus returns videos for every user and not only for the user with id 1.

Second problem is that $user->channel does not get hydrated and I end up with 1+n problem. According to documentation (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#result-format) changing DQL to SELECT v,ch FROM ... should populate the $channel property but all it does is that array returned by $query->getResult() contains both Video and Channel objects.

Do you know how to fix this, especially the first problem?

Comment: For the second problem you need to specify all the objects you want hydrated with SELECT u,ch,v.  For the first problem you probably want to start with the user and link from there.  SELECT FROM User LEFT JOIN channel LEFT JOIN video.  Probably need to experiment a bit with that.

Comment: doctrine is smart enough to understand the following: `... FROM App\Entity\Video v INNER JOIN v.channel ch INNER JOIN ch.users u WHERE u = :user`, which replaces the complete join with the actual associations you defined. as Cerad noted adding ch to the select clause *should* help somewhat, however, it might only help for n:1 associations. other hydrations are actually hard. If you're coming from the channel side, user.channels can't be hydrated with this query, really. because the set might be incomplete. there might exist a channel without a video for example.

Comment: However, `$user->channels` should always be just one query. And **after** you've done this query, accessing any of your video's `$video->channel` should *not* cause another query, since video has only one channel, which it knows the id of, and doctrine caches all its managed objects and can return the channel for the id. however, I'm not quite certain if doctrine will notice it already has all the channels' videos, if you're going for `$channel->videos`. Essentially: it's all in the order of queries and data queried.

Comment: finally: lazy fetching is weird to define, because it's the default (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html#extra-lazy-associations). setting it to either EAGER or EXTRA_LAZY might actually do something relevant. possibly EAGER for video.channel and omitting it for the others might be sensible. I hope your Many-To-Many has a `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`.

Comment: Thank you, this dql works:
 SELECT v,ch FROM App\Entity\Video v 
            INNER JOIN v.channel ch
            INNER JOIN ch.subscribers u
            WHERE u = :user
            ORDER BY v.updated DESC

It fixed both n+1 and proper select